# Run 2 apart code with few wile loops with time.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some problem, i need to run separate code in apart while loops

example:

```
    import time
while True:
    time.sleep(5)

    print('\ntime 5 s')

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\ntime 1 s')
```

i know, this is not working, but how to initiate it like this output:

```
time 1 s
time 1 s
time 1 s
time 1 s
time 1 s
time 5 s
```

Comment: You'll need to run each loop in a separate thread. Otherwise they will execute in a sequential manner (first loop, then second loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to run each loop in a separate thread, otherwise they will execute in a sequential manner, i.e., first loop and then second loop (which will never execute, since the first loop executes forever).

For example:

```
import time
import threading

def func1():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\ntime 1 s')

def func5():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print('\ntime 5 s')

threads = [threading.Thread(target=func) for func in [func1,func5]]
for thread in threads: thread.start()
for thread in threads: thread.join()
```